# Cannot pop to previous View Controller in Swift 4

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to go back to my previous view controller, 
I tried multiple ways, 
first I tried using

```
_ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

which doesn't work and I don't get any error message for that.

then I tried doing :

```
let viewControllers: [UIViewController] = self.navigationController!.viewControllers as [UIViewController];
self.navigationController!.popToViewController(viewControllers[viewControllers.count - 2], animated: true);
```

which crashes with the error:

```
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

What am I doing wrong?
And how can I go back to my previous view controller?

Comment: `self.navigationController` is nil? Do you have really a `UINavigationController`?

Comment: Your view controller doesn't have a navigation controller.

Comment: It would also be interesting to know how you presented your second view controller. If you used `present`, going back is different from `navigationController?.pushViewController`.

Comment: If you use nav maybe the viewControllers.count - 2 is not valid